# Installing PHPUnit without using pear

Tags: phpunit

How can I install PHPUnit without using PEAR (and offline)?

I'm currently using Window Vista with XAMPP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays PHPUnit is available as a single file, which takes care of all its dependencies. See this answer for installation details:

[NetBeans + multiple php versions + phpUnit without PEAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444412/netbeans-multiple-php-versions-phpunit-without-pear/14904926#14904926)

Answer (score 2):

You don't really want that. See the dependencies on http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html - installing them manually is a pain.

What you could do is downloading all pear packages on one machine with `pear download $packagename` and installing them on the offline machine with pear, too - but offline.

You'll also need phpunit's `channel.xml` file to get the channel registered offline, http://pear.phpunit.de/channel.xml.

Answer (score 0):

thz . Mine is just copy and paste the whole php folder from successor one to me . all fine now .