# NetBeans + multiple php versions + phpUnit without PEAR

Tags: php, iis, netbeans, phpunit

My problem is a little bit complicated. I have multiple php versions on IIS. Every php project has its own php version and domain name, for example: www.webshop.loc... I'm developing the projects via NetBeans, and I'd like to use TDD as development process.

My problem is: how to install the phpUnit without installing PEAR or opening any DOS style windows, and how to setup phpUnit to use different php versions on different projects?

(Hmm 99% that's not possible. :S)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to install phpunit after 1.5 year, so this is the up to date answer now.

I simply used composer with these settings: [PHPUnit via Composer and PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814263/phpunit-via-composer-and-phpstorm), and it worked!

I use phpstorm now instead of netbeans, in that I can configure different php interpreter and phpunit settings for each project. I did not follow the changes in netbeans, maybe in the new versions it's capable of that too, but version 7.1 was not enough for that.

Answer (score 5):

I can answer the installation part: Installing **PHPUnit without PEAR** and using it in NetBeans is actually super easy ever since PHPUnit has been made available as **phar archive**.

After downloading the phar files and creating the 2 batch files, everything works great.

- http://pear.phpunit.de/get/phpunit.phar
- http://pear.phpunit.de/get/phpunit-skelgen.phar

Create a `phpunit.bat` file in the same directory with the following content:

```
@echo off
"C:\PathToYourPHPInstall\php.exe" "C:\PathToPHPUnit\phpunit.phar" %*
```

Create a `phpunit-skelgen.bat` file in the same directory with the following content:

```
@echo off
"C:\PathToYourPHPInstall\php.exe" "C:\PathToPHPUnit\phpunit-skelgen.phar" %*
```

In NetBeans go to *Tools -> Options -> PHP -> Unit Testing*, select your bat files and you're good to go!

Comment: Using simpleTest for a while, so this question is not actual anymore.

Comment: Edorian answered the same: "There is a fully working PHPUnit.phar on the way but it's not there yet. That would make the "installing" part easier."

Comment: I tried out, but does not work if you have whitespace character in the path... I don't have more time for this phpunit stuff, thanks the answer btw.

Comment: thanks a lot man! was looking several hours how to config this stuff.. so simple at the end ...

Answer (score 2):

Good news: It's possible. I've done it :)

Bad news: It's not going to be pretty.

---

#### Installing

My suggestion would be to add the PHPUnit files to your repository. For a guide on how to do this see [**`the 'using from a git checkout' section of the PHPUnit manual`**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/).

You can pick the right branches and module versions for each project. See this [downgrading phpunit guide for the right module versions](http://dustyreagan.com/downgrade-phpunit-3-6-to-3-5-15/) or look at the docs of the appropriate git branch!

#### Usage

I'd then suggest setting up one `phpunit-projectname.bat` or something.

In that file use something like `php-YOUR.VERSION -c the-needed-ini.ini your/projects/phpunit.php $passAllArguments` for each project.

That runs well even so upgrading is quite annoying.

---

There is a fully working PHPUnit.phar on the way but it's not there yet. That would make the "installing" part easier.

---

#### General

To run one `PHPUnit` with multiple php versions all you need to do is `your/php /path/to/your/phpunit` and it will take that version instead of the "default" one.

Comment: Can you explain me more detailed how to create that bat files and how to pass them to the netbeans project? I don't want to use phpunit from command line, I want to use it from netbeans...

Comment: You create a file `phpnunit-project.bat` with `C:\your-needed-php-version\PHP\php.exe -c C:\path\to\your\phpunit-version\php-ini-with-include-path.ini C:\path\to\your\phpunit-version\phpunit` and thats it. Just tell netbeans thats the "phpunit executable" then.

Comment: I'll try it out, but now I have troubles with the portable phpunit from git: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit . I don't want to install PEAR for this if isn't necessary... But it seems like not working. It fails on selftests or what :S

Answer (score 1):

To update webd0de answer, the download URLs for both phar files have changed.

They are:

phpphar: https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
phpunit-skelgen.phar: https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-skelgen.phar

After downloading the phar files and creating the 2 batch files, everything works great.