# Cannot find PHPUnit in include path phpstorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

`Cannot find PHPUnit in include path` is the error message I get when I try to run my code in phpstorm.

In the PHP Settings, my  PHP level language is `5.4 (traits, short array syntax, etc.)` and interpreter is `Name(5.4.7)` where `Name` is user defined.

The error appears when I try to run the code and the exact message is this:

> C:\xampp2\php\php.exe C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php --no-configuration
>
> C:\xampp2\htdocs\ft-website
>
> Testing started at 2:34 PM ...
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
>
> Cannot find PHPUnit in include path (.;C:\xampp2\php\PEAR)`

Comment: You should do exactly as error message says: add the path where PHPUnit files are located to the `include_path` config variable in your `php.ini`

Comment: Is PHPUnit actually installed in `C:\xampp2\php\PEAR`? The best way to go would be to either install it there using PEAR, or adjust your PHP include path to a PHPUnit installation at another location.

Comment: I have a `php\pear` folder. I'm just going to go ahead and install using PEAR and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Just encountered this problem myself.

I'm unsure why it is unable to find PHPUnit in the include path (despite the fact that it *is* there, albeit in all lowercase).

I got around this by changing my IntelliJ Preferences for PHPUnit (under `PHP --> PHPUnit`). I changed the `PHPUnit library` settings to `Use custom loader` and then specified the path to the `phpunit` executable. On my mac, that was `/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.26/bin/phpunit`.

UPDATE:

I just discovered that `pear` now installs PHPUnit as a `phar` named `phpunit`. It previously installed the PHPUnit source, which was really nice for reference and code completion in PHPStorm. I think that this is the reason things aren't working any longer with PHPStorm, because it's expecting a php executable and not a php archive.

So, I'm moving away from using `pear` to install PHPUnit, and I'm using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) instead. This bundles PHPUnit directly as a dependency of my project, which makes it more portable than a system dependency. You'll need to add `vendor/phpunit/phpunit` as a PHP include path in your PHPStorm preferences. This will serve two purposes:

1. PHPStorm can find the `phpunit` executable now
2. PHPStorm will index all the `PHPUnit` classes now, so you'll get auto-complete. Yay!

To do this, go to Languages and Frameworks in the PhpStorm settings.
If you click on PHP, on the right you have your include paths

Comment: sorry, how do I add `vendor/phpunit/phpunit` as a PHP include path?  I'm unclear.

Comment: For drupal8 path will be `/PATH/TO/DRUPAL/core/tests/bootstrap.php`

Comment: When using Laravel Homestead, remeber not to use local interpreter, but remote one. For the first time you must add it in Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> PHPUnit using green plus in upper left corner

Answer (score 25):

I had this problem after adding PHPUnit via composer.

I fixed this by choosing `use custom autoloader` in `Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> PHP -> PHPUnit`, then adding /vendor/autoload.php as the location of the custom autoloader.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a relative path unfortunately. Don't know why I would have to correct this each time I work on a project.

Comment: I combined this with @Ben's answer above and now it works (using IntelliJ).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Ben's answer, in phpStorm 7.1.3 it works by specifying the phpunit.phar location under the "use custom loader" option, for example:

"Path to script: /usr/share/php/phpunit.phar"

Comment: Please add more description to your answer. It will help questioner in grasping more out of your answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way to do it without using composer, and using your global phpunit.

1. Phpunit now comes with a phar file. My path was ***/usr/local/Cellar/phpunit/5.0.0/libexec/phpunit-5.0.0.phar***

[image]

2. PhpStorm Preferences **->** Path to phpunit.phar **->** select the phpunit phar

[image]

3. That's all, good stuff.

Comment: To get autocompletion, the directory containing the phar can be added as an include path. In the image above it would be `/usr/local/Cellar/phpunit/5.0.0/libexec/`.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem for PHPStorm 2017 using Vagrant. First go to `Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> PHP` and Add a remote interpreter, then go to `Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> PHP -> PHPUnit` click the + on top and click `by Remote Interpreter`. If you're using Composer autoloader, then enter your full Vagrant path to your autoloader file.

Comment: I exactly needs this, but cannot make it work. If I run the test I still get "Cannot find PHPUnit in include path". I did what you wrote - so can you plz give some more detailed information on that?

Comment: Ok found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814263/phpunit-via-composer-and-phpstorm - basically I had to do "Select Use custom loader and then enter the autoload.php" - so actually I just did not understood your answer fully ;-)

Comment: Glad my answer helped :)

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, to fix the same issue when using PHPStorm + Vagrant + PHPUnit by defining path to the ***global phpunit.phar*** (not composer)

While the tests runned successfully, I was missing the code completion. I had confirmed that `phpunit` was in the PATH on my local machine, and to make sure, I had added `/usr/local/bin` to the PHP Include paths in `PHP Settings`. Still no code completion.

The reason: PHPstorm was looking for `phpunit.phar`, not just `phpunit`. To fix, on my local machine I established a symlink `phpunit.phar` pointing to `phpunit`:

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin/
$ sudo ln -s phpunit phpunit.phar
```

Then I reindexed the project, and code completion started working.

Answer (score 0):

For those that are looking at it in 2020, starting from PHPStorm 2019 this is under:

```
Languages and Frameworks->PHP->Test Frameworks
```

1. Choose to add a new library
2. Select "PHPUnit"
3. Select "Path to phpunit.phar" radio
4. You'll have an automatic option to download PHPUnit