# Install PHPUnit on OSX Mavericks

Tags: php, macos, phpunit, pear, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install PHPUnit on my MBP with OSX Mavericks.
The install part is going great, pear throws no errors, exceptions or whatsoever. But when I try to execute the phpunit command in terminal it does throw an error.

I've searched far and wide for an answer, but I can't find anything that solves the problem.

This is what happens:

- Installing PHPUnit (*pear install phpunit/PHPUnit*) it's saying it's already installed (that's correct).
- When I list all the installed packages in pear (*pear list*), PHPUnit does not show up in the list.
- When I execute the *pear list-all* command it shows up twice as PHPUNIT (which is version 1.3.2) and PHPUNIT2 (version 2.3.6).
- And when I try to execute the phpunit command it throws an error (twice):

> PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'File/Iterator/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /usr/local/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64

[image: Terminal Output]

EDIT: I had it working on Mountain Lion, but since I've upgraded to Mavericks phpunit was broken. Also, I've checked the directory of the autoload.php, and the file is there..

Can somebody please explain what's going on? It's starting to drive me mad..

Comment: That's not really an answer, but I have recently converted all my projects so they load PHPUnit via Composer. It's much easier to setup. Also, no matter which OS and environment you or your colleagues use, PHPUnit is always available when you `composer install`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm looking in to it, it sounds promising!
Quick question, does this work with XAMPP? And if yes, how?

Comment: You are welcome. Make sure you include autoload.php from composer to have all PHPUnit classes available for your testing. It's pretty straightforward with PHPStorm, which I use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814263/phpunit-via-composer-and-phpstorm

Comment: Not sure if it helps but my last install of PHPUnit (recent but not on Mavericks) was via pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit so 'sudo pear upgrade-all', 'sudo pear config-set auto_discover 1', 'sudo pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit'

Comment: That unfortunately didn't help. No upgrade was found and the install couldn't be executed since PHPUnit is already installed.

Comment: In Sander's case, the problem is related to sub-package File_Iterator, so installing them will probably fix issue. I'm running without a problem PHPUnit on OS X Maverick which was installed via PEAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use the IDE PHPStorm and Composer. Which gives the advantage to install dependencies on a project base.

Thanks to Paves S. for the recommendation.

For more information on how to install:

http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/enabling-phpunit-support.html

Answer (score 0):

If you installed php using MacPorts, you need to set your `include_path` in php.ini to:

```
include_path = ".:/opt/local/lib/php/:/opt/local/lib/php/PEAR/"
```

I also reinstalled PHPUnit, as there were some dependancies issues (Generator.php missing):

You can run this as root (found this script [here](https://gist.github.com/jmathai/2927956) and added --alldeps option when reinstalling):

```
pear list -c phpunit | grep stable | awk '{print "phpunit/"$1}' | xargs pear uninstall
pear install --alldeps phpunit/phpunit
```