# setting up phpstorm phpunit and composer

Tags: php, composer-php, phpstorm

i know there are many questions asked about this before. but the issue is none of them is helping me in anyway?
There is no step by step configuration help..

The most colosest good help i think i could find is here in stackoverflow answer.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814263/phpunit-via-composer-and-phpstorm
```

The answer provided by **@Adam Lynch** should be explained more clearly, As not everyone is expert in this debugging.

I recently installed xdebug for php today for the first time on windows 8.

Now as i am using phpstorm so went to setup the xdebug settings for phpstorm and couldn't make it to work, so i start searching net and it seemed ppl liked composer more then pear.
So i downloaded and installed `composer` from here.

```
https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md
```

Seems to me composer installed successfully, but now still there is issue of setting composer with phpstorm.

**THERE IS NO `VENDOR` DIRECTORY**

Gosh... i want to tell this to the person who answered in that stackoverflow. xD. i know its crazy. but i am banging banging my head over walls, no matter how much searches i do there is no vendor directory came with composer installation.???

Now how to setup the autoload.php from vendor directory if there is no vendor directory.
**There is only composer.phar file.**
[image]

what to put in below picture?
[image]

its been hours, i am stucked and cant find my way out of it :(

---

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @LazyOne, i now know that vendor directory will come if i define any dependency.
Now as i moved forward to install Dependency i got this error.
[image]

This is how i tried to install it.
[image]

Comment: So .. did you installed PHPUnit via composer? The `vendor` folder will be created when you have at least one local package installed via composer.

Comment: @LazyOne
Thankyou for reply, i tried to install package as you asked, i searched net to find the way to install but eventually found the place. However when i tried to install PHPUnit, i got error,
I updated my question. Please check.

Comment: Install from command line (terminal/console): just go to the project root and issue composer commands there -- that's how I do -- I do not rely on using composer via PhpStorm as it often fails to do basic things for me (no clue why).

Comment: I have voted for this question tu be closed as "too broad". While I appreciate your desire for a step by step tutorial for setting up this environment, Stack Overflow's format is not very suitable to host such a tutorial, nor to act as an index linking somewhere else. Extended discussions back and forth similarly break the one-question-per-page model of the site.